# Proper place to include the license of a dependency

Tags: gpl, mit, linked-libraries, dependencies

I'm developing a GPLv3 project, and i need to use both the [feather's icon set](https://github.com/feathericons/feather#feather), licensed with MIT license, and the [PyQt5 library](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/license-faq) with GPL. I don't need to rewrite or extend any content of the these projects, i just need to to include the icon set in my final binary, and dinamically link the PyQt5 library.

I'm afraid that, since I'm using a Github repository to host my project, adding more things to the current LICENSE file may confuse the github's algorithm to detect the license of my project, as well as making these additions hard to find.

- For each of these dependencies, do I need to include their license(or copyright notice) in my repository?
- If so, where is the appropriate place to keep the license/notice of these dependencies? It is okay to keep it outside of the LICENSE file?
- For each of these dependencies, do I need to distribute their license/notice along with the binary distribution of my project?

---

**edit:** I want to use `git submodule` with the icon set project,  which means that my repository won't contain the icon set, but `git` can be used to automatically download it(with its license) whenever someone clone my repository. Anyway, I still need to bundle the icon set with my project's binary, so i'm not sure whether including its license that way is sufficient.

---

Comment: Linking to pyqt5 only needs a mention it in your readme or documentation. Are you copying the icons into your project? Then have a copy of the icons license in the folder with them. If your project relies on the icons being installed before your project is built, then like pyqt5 you only need a mention it in your docs.

Comment: Thanks. About the icons, i think it is closer to the first case (copying the project), but not entirely. I'll edit the question to add clarifications.